# Why am I getting undefined method errors for "strip" and "downcase" when I run RSpec on my models?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I am running an RSpec test on a model and getting errors for string methods such as: "index, "downcase," and "strip."  Any ideas why that is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are getting "undefined method", then the object you are operating on is likely not a string.  Try printing out the result from `.class` before calling `.strip`, etc and see what type of object you are working with.  A function that normally returns a string might return a non-string (like `nil`) on error, and you may be operating on something like that inadvertently.

Comment: Yes!  Thanks bta, that worked.  I specified .to_s before calling .strip and that worked perfectly.  It seems like the app runs fine without the .to_s, performing the strips and the downcases as planned. RSpec is clearly anal about the type.  Thanks again.